# Value parsed to observable before being subscribed to

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, observable

I have a service (data.service.ts) and a component (page.component.ts).

In this data.service.ts service there is an observable called `changes$`

When I load my page it successfully gets the data from storage and parses (using .next()) to the observable.

In my page.component.ts component it is subscribed to this observable, every following changes do get handled but the first one (on page load) does not.

Why? My data.service.ts parses the data (using .next()) before the page.component.ts is subscribed to this `changes$` observable.

What would be the best way to "wait" till the component is subscribed?

I've found a workaround using `setTimeout(() => { ... }, 0)` but it doesn't feel right (if you know what I mean)

Here is some code:

data.service.ts:

```
export class DoorService implements OnDestroy {
    private data: DoorServiceData;

    private destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();
    private changesSubject$: Subject<IDoorSettings> = new Subject();
    // this way users cannot parse values to the subject. read-only...
    public changes$: Observable<IDoorSettings> = this.changesSubject$.asObservable().pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$));

    constructor(){
        this.init();
    }


    // service initializer, set data etc. 
    private init() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let savedData: DoorServiceData = this.getFromStorage();
            if(!savedData)
            {
                savedData =  {settings: {usedInStore: false, isValid: false}};
            }
            this.data = savedData;
            this.changesSubject$.next(this.data.settings);
            console.log("DOOR SERVICE DATA SET");
        }, 0)
    }
}
```

page.component.ts:

```
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit{
    public settings: IDoorSettings;

    constructor(public doorService: DoorService) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.watchSettings();
    }

    private watchSettings() {
        console.log("Watching settings");
        this.doorService.changes$.subscribe((val) => {
            this.settings = val;
        });
    }
}
```

Using the chrome console I can tell it parses the data before the component is subscribed (**when I don't use the "setTimeout" workaround**)

What would be the best way to handle this scenario?

I've also tried the `async` pipe, but no luck there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried with a BehaviorSubject instead of a Subject? 
https://www.learnrxjs.io/subjects/behaviorsubject.html

Comment: @DavideBellone Why should a BehaviorSubject work instead of a Subject if the value is read from the `changes$` **observable**?

Comment: Because when you subscribe to a Subject you are notified only for values emitted after the subscription. With BehaviorSubject you set an initial value, then when you subscribe the first value emitted is the one stored in the BehaviorSubject. 

If I've understood well your problem, this should be the solution

Comment: Lok at this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-7sp1rw?devtoolsheight=60

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of Subject you should BehaviourSubject or ReplaySubject.

> What would be the best way to "wait" till the component is subscribed?

Sir, this is a scary thought to have, when in RxJS world. It's like the Radio Station should wait for playing songs, till at least one of the listeners tune in.

Continuing with the eg of Radio Station, what you are telling me, is that as soon as you tune in, the first song is gone.Hence you add  BehaviourSubject or ReplaySubject.

The BehaviorSubject has the characteristic that it stores the “current” value. This means that you can always directly get the last emitted value from the BehaviorSubject.So as soon as you tune in to the radio, the last played song will be played.

```js
const subject = new Rx.BehaviorSubject(Math.random());

// subscriber 1
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber A:', data);
});

// output
// Subscriber A: 0.24957144215097515
```

The ReplaySubject is comparable to the BehaviorSubject in the way that it can send “old” values to new subscribers. It however has the extra characteristic that it can record a part of the observable execution and therefore store multiple old values and “replay” them to new subscribers.
When creating the ReplaySubject you can specify how much values you want to store and for how long you want to store them. In other words you can specify: “I want to store the last 2 values, that have been executed in the last 100ms prior to a new subscription”.

```js
const subject = new Rx.ReplaySubject(2, 100);

// subscriber 1
subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber A:', data);
});

setInterval(() => subject.next(Math.random()), 200);

// subscriber 2
setTimeout(() => {
  subject.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Subscriber B:', data);
  });
}, 1000)

// Subscriber A: 0.44524184251927656
// Subscriber A: 0.5802631630066313
// Subscriber A: 0.9792165506699135
// Subscriber A: 0.3239616040117268
// Subscriber A: 0.6845077617520203
// Subscriber B: 0.6845077617520203
// Subscriber A: 0.41269171141525707
// Subscriber B: 0.41269171141525707
// Subscriber A: 0.8211466186035139
// Subscriber B: 0.8211466186035139
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a RepleySubject instead of Subject

```
 private changesSubject$: ReplaySubject<IDoorSettings> = new ReplaySubject(1);
```